# How to automatically process contents of <textarea> without user pressing a button?

Tags: ajax, textarea

On my page I have a textarea where users can enter a list of items, items being separated by a newline.

I would like to process the user's input without him/her having to press a submit button. ("Process" means send the information the user entered to the server and update other elements on the current page.) I thought of two days of doing this:

1- Install an event handler for keypress events and, when I get an event for the Enter key being pressed, process the line the user just completed. (Getting cursor position info as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341233/getting-cursor-position-in-a-textarea).) This has the disadvantage of not handling copy-pasting into the form. (And, if I understood correctly from browsing Stack Overflow, support for handling paste events is [not great](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html) even among most common browsers, right?)

2- Periodically process the contents of the textarea by using setInterval(). I am already using a setInterval() on the page to implement the [unique URLs pattern](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs), so if I could I would avoid that.

Are there better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also an "onchange" event for a textarea. You can use it to detect any changes, including paste or magic inserts.

Comment: @alemjerus: thanks, that is helpful! I will listen for that event.